# Reading images in a loop gets slower

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have to process a batch of images (around 30000) in a for loop. For this I read one image with every execution of the loop.

When reaching a certain index (the exact value varies but usually it is around 2000) the progress slows dramatically (factor 2 or 3). How can this be?

Here is a minimal code example that shows this behavior:

```
imgFolder = [uigetdir, '/'];
files = dir(fullfile(imgFolder, '*.tiff'));
filenames = sort_nat({files.name});

imshow(imread([imgFolder, '/', filenames{1}]))
roi = roipoly;

meansRGB = zeros(3,length(files));
tic;

for i = 1:size(files,1)
    img = imread([imgFolder, '/', filenames{i}]);
    % for j=1:3
       % a = regionprops(roi,img(:,:,j),'PixelValues');
       % meansRGB(j,i) = mean(a.PixelValues);
    % end

    % show remaining time
    dt = 500; % display remaining time every dt'th step
    if(mod(i,dt)) == 0
        disp(i)
        elapsed = toc;
        remainingSeconds = elapsed*(length(files)-i)/dt;
        [hours, minutes, seconds] = sec2hms(remainingSeconds);
        str = sprintf('remaining time: %d:%d:%d', hours, minutes, round(seconds));
        disp(str);
        tic;
    end
end
```

Note that all the important parts that I thought would consume the most time are already commented out and are not the reason for the decelerating loop. Also there is plenty of RAM and processor cycles left, this shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping?

Could it be that the first few hundred images fill up your RAM?

Any other accesses to memory would trigger swapping and writing to the hard drive, which is easily orders of magnitude slower...

Comment: No, I was editing my question to include this while you typed. I have several GB of RAM left and the load doesn't get bigger since I overwrite the img variable with every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that `imread()` is leaving file handles open? (Though I'd be rather surprised if that were the case?)

You could maybe try sticking an `fclose('all')` in the loop to check?